# Correct method for up-sampling cross-power spectrum for sub-pixel motion estimation

Tags: matlab, fft, estimation, motion

Let's say I have two images, one reference($g$) and another shifted($f$). I tried to get subpixel accuracy of the motion. Here are my steps:

1. Firstly I would calculate the normalized cross-power spectrum $C(u,v)$, where $F$ and $G$ are `fft2`-ed.

$$C(u,v)=\dfrac{F(u,v)G^*(u,v)}{\lvert F(u,v)G^*(u,v) \rvert} $$

2. Next I would like to get $1/k$ subpixel accuracy, by `padarray` the $C(u,v)$ by $k$ factor, resulting in $C_k(u,v)$
3. `ifft2` $C_k(u,v)$, resulting in $c_k(x,y)$
4. Find the arg max of the $c_k(x,y)$

Here's my code in Matlab:

```
reference = fft2(reference);
shifted = fft2(shifted);
C=shifted.*conj(reference)./abs(shifted.*conj(reference));
[m, n]=size(reference);
ck=ifft2(padarray(C,[k*m k*n],'both'));
[~,w] = max(real(ck(:)));
[dxk,dyk] = ind2sub(size(ck),w);
```

After run the code I can't get the accurate result. I hope I explained it clear enough(from what I understood from the attached paper). I really need help on this and much appreciate any help!

Referred paper: [Here](https://mega.nz/#!PoklnaJR!hj_Bejha6owN1TyyxodM-F-OGvjdZYlyJImNapALXLA) (start from section 3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Preface

I know the OP asked for Matlab, but if you follow our discussion [here in the Mathematica chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35824445#35824445) it seems any answer will be helpful. Therefore, I'm going to present the approach, visualizing each step, so it can be repeated and debugged in Matlab.

## Answer

The approach itself is simple and as far as I can see there are only two things to keep in mind. But first things first. I'm using a downscaled version of the Lena image that can be accessed in Mathematica through `ExampleData`. I shifted it by `{-5.3, 8.7}` pixels which can be done through `ImageTransformation` in combination with `TranslationTransform`.

```
{dx, dy} = {-5.3, 8.7};

gImg = ImageResize[
   ColorConvert[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], "Grayscale"], 128];
{nx, ny} = ImageDimensions[gImg];
fImg = ImageTransformation[gImg, TranslationTransform[{dx, dy}/{nx, ny}]];

{gData, fData} = ImageData /@ {gImg, fImg};
```

Keep in mind that shifting the image by fractions of pixel units will resample it and introduce some blur that degrades the image. Therefore, I would not expect that the perfect solution can be found.

What we have in `gData` and `fData` are the pixel values of the images which look like this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

#### Fourier transform

I don't know how `fft2` in Matlab exactly works, but usually, taking the Fourier transform of an image does not result where the frequencies are centered. Let me give you an example, by showing how the spectrum looks if you just use `FourierTransform`

```
Image[Fourier[gData] // Abs]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To make the upscaling by padding work, we need to center the transform. You can do this, by multiplying each pixel by $(-1)^{x+y}$ which gives a chessboard-like fashion. This is explained in detail in the very easy to read [Digital Imageprocessing by Gonzalez and Woods](http://www.imageprocessingplace.com/). A pdf of the 2nd edition can be found [here](http://web.ipac.caltech.edu/staff/fmasci/home/astro_refs/Digital_Image_Processing_2ndEd.pdf) and you should follow the discussion on page 154.

In Mathematica, a function to transform an image into this chessboard-like form can be written down as

```
centerFrequency[data_] := With[{d = Dimensions[data]},
   Table[(-1)^(i + j)*data[[j, i]], {j, Last[d]}, {i,
      First[d]}]
   ];
```

If we now look at the same spectrum, with this function applied before using the FFT, we get the expected result:

```
Image[Fourier[centerFrequency@gData] // Abs]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

#### Normalized Cross Power Spectrum

To create an upscaled version of the normalized cross-power spectrum, we follow exactly what is written in the paper

1. Calculate the centered fourier transform of `fData` and `gData` into `f` and `g`
2. Conjugate `g`
3. Calculate `f*g/Norm[f*g]`
4. Pad the result by a factor `k` of the original image dimension (I assume a square image in this example)

In code this looks like this

```
normCrossPow[ref_, tmpl_, k_] := Module[{
  f = Fourier[centerFrequency@ref], 
  g = Conjugate[Fourier[centerFrequency@tmpl]], nx
  },
  nx = First[Dimensions[ref]]/2;
  ArrayPad[f*g/Norm[f*g], k*nx]
]
```

To get the resulting spectrum, we only need to apply `InverseFourier`, apply `centerFrequencies` again and look at the real part of the complex array.

```
spec = Re[
   centerFrequency@InverseFourier[normCrossPow[fData, gData, 3]]
];
Image[spec] // ImageAdjust
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Above, I used a factor of `k=3`.
The white spot in the upper right corner is our maximum we are interested in. Let us find the position of this maximum

```
max = FirstPosition[spec, Max[Flatten[spec]]]
```

This gives `{36, 22}`. Keep in mind, that the y-axis in image coordinates and matrix-coordinates is reversed and that in a matrix the y-values comes first. Additionally, if images have no shift at all, the maximum would be at `{1,1}` and we need to divide out our factor `k` again. Note that we divide by 4 (!!) because with a factor of `k=1` we would divide by 1, with `k=1` by 2, and so on.

```
({36, 22} - {1, 1})/4.0
```

This gives `{8.75, 5.25}` for `{dy, dx}` but remember that it is actually `dy=-8.75` because of the reversed y-axis.

Now, we can use this result and back-transform our `fImg`

```
res = ImageTransformation[fImg, TranslationTransform[{5.25, -8.75}/{nx, ny}]]
```

and look at the combined image of `gImg` and `res`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Fits nicely and the only error we see is the black border that was introduced by initially transforming `fImg`.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! It really meant a lot to me! However, when I re-implement the steps in matlab, I could get accurate dx, but not dy. Any ideas why was it? I would get something like this `[dx=3.5000  dy=247.2500`, which the dy is relatively large. The actual should be around `dy=8.7400` This is the [code](http://pastebin.com/SZEDHxKX), it should be understandable in both platform. Thank you once again!

Comment: The same can happen to `dx` if the shift is in the other direction! Just think about it, when the maximum (now in the upper left corner) would move further to the left, it is reflected to the right side of the image. The same happens with `dy`. You need to calculate something like `ny-dy` if `dy` is larger than `ny/2`. Here, `ny` is the number of pixels in y direction.

Comment: Yes! How insensitive of me! Thank you so so much @halirutan ! You saved my day! And sorry for disturbing your Saturday :)